# Can we install PDO and keep the old MySQL extension without any conflict?

Tags: mysql, pdo, installation

I'm starting to notice that most of the functions in MySQL are becoming deprecated and suggest us to move to MySQLi or PDO.

The only thing is that we have a lot of clients on our servers that have legacy MySQL code and we can't change them all.

Is it possible to run both drivers without any problems in CentOS / cPanel ? If I install PDO through EasyApache in the WHM, would it broke something?

I need some advice on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they can work side by side without a problem.

Comment: Point in fact, depending on your version of PHP they already do (i.e. mysql and mysqli).

Comment: @JasonMcCreary well that's another thing, our server is still running on 5.2.17 and I know that upgrade it to 5.3.* would mess a lot of things on older websites :S

Comment: Well, you _can_ configure the webserver to run 2 different versions of PHP, a question best (after googled for) on serverfault.com though. Personally I find it easier to run 2 or more instances of apache behind a proxy.